# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple and how to fix it

Tags: python, error-handling

**I keep on getting this error message every time I run my game that I wrote in Python using Pygame. The error message is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Memory Puzzle_20171029.py", line 248, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/Memory Puzzle_20171029.py", line 58, in main
    startGameAnimation(mainBoard)
  File "/home/pi/Memory Puzzle_20171029.py", line 226, in startGameAnimation
    revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxGroups)
  File "/home/pi/Memory Puzzle_20171029.py", line 192, in revealBoxesAnimation
    drawBoxCovers(board, boxesToReveal, coverage)
  File "/home/pi/Memory Puzzle_20171029.py", line 182, in drawBoxCovers
    left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(box[0], box[1])
  File "/home/pi/Memory Puzzle_20171029.py", line 144, in leftTopCoordsOfBox
    left = boxx*(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + XMARGIN
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

**Please help, I am a beginner in programming and don't know all the errors in Python. I would be very grateful if you can offer your knowledge and help me fix this problem
Thanks!!!**

Here is my script for my game

```
import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
REVEALSPEED = 8
BOXSIZE = 40
GAPSIZE = 10
BOARDWIDTH = 10
BOARDHEIGHT = 7
assert (BOARDWIDTH * BOARDHEIGHT) % 2 == 0,'Board needs to have an even number of boxes for pairs of matches.'
XMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (BOARDWIDTH*(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE)))/2)
YMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (BOARDHEIGHT*(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE)))/2)

GRAY = (100, 100, 100)
NAVYBLUE = (60, 60, 100)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = ( 0, 0,255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
CYAN = ( 0, 255, 255)

BGCOLOR = NAVYBLUE
LIGHTBGCOLOR = GRAY
BOXCOLOR = WHITE
HIGHLIGHTCOLOR = BLUE

DONUT = 'donut'
SQUARE = 'square'
DIAMOND = 'diamond'
LINES = 'lines'
OVAL = 'oval'

ALLCOLORS = (RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW, ORANGE, PURPLE, CYAN)
ALLSHAPES = (DONUT, SQUARE, DIAMOND, LINES, OVAL)
assert len(ALLCOLORS) * len(ALLSHAPES)*2 >= BOARDWIDTH*BOARDHEIGHT, 'Board is too big for the number of shapes/colors defined.'

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

    mousex = 0
    mousey = 0
    pygame.display.set_caption('Memory Game')

    mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
    revealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

    firstSelection = None

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    startGameAnimation(mainBoard)

    while True:
        mouseClicked = False

        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                mouseClicked = True

        boxx, boxy = getBoxAtPixel(mousex, mousey)
        if boxx != None and boxy != None:
            if not revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy]:
                drawHighlightBox(boxx, boxy)
            if not revealedBoxes[boxx, boxy] and mouseClicked:
                revealBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(boxx, boxy)])
                revealedBoxes [boxx, boxy] = True
                if fisrtSelection == None:
                    fisrtSelection = (boxx, boxy)
                else:
                    icon1shape, icon1color = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, firstSelection[0], firstselection[1])
                    icon2shape, icon2color = getShapeAndColor(mainBoard, boxx, boxy)

                    if icon1shape != icon2shape or icon1color:
                        pygame.time.wait(1000)
                        coverBoxesAnimation(mainBoard, [(firstSelection[0], firstSelection[1]), (boxx, boxy)])
                        revealedBoxes[firstSelection[0]][firstSelection[1]] = False
                        revealedBoxes[boxx][boxy] = False
                    elif hasWon(revealedBoxes):
                        gameWonAnimation(mainBoard)
                        pygame.time.wait(2000)

                        mainBoard = getRandomizedBoard()
                        revealedBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)

                        drawBoard(mainBoard, revealedBoxes)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        pygame.time.wait(1000)

                        startGameAnimation(mainBoard)
                    firstSelection = None


                pygame.display.update()
                FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
def generateRevealedBoxesData(val):
    revealedBoxes =[]
    for i in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        revealedBoxes.append([val] * BOARDHEIGHT)
    return revealedBoxes

def getRandomizedBoard():
    icons = [1]
    for color in ALLCOLORS:
        for shape in ALLSHAPES:
            icons.append((shape, color))

    random.shuffle(icons)
    numIconsUsed = int(BOARDWIDTH * BOARDHEIGHT / 2)
    icons = icons[:numIconsUsed] * 2
    random.shuffle(icons)

    board = [0]
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        column = []
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            column.append(icons[0])
            del icons[0]
            board.append(column)
            return board

def splitIntoGroupsOf(groupSize, theList):
    result = []
    for i in range (0, len(theList), groupSize):
        result.append(theList[i:i +groupSize])
    return result

def leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy):
    left = boxx*(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + XMARGIN
    top = boxy * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + YMARGIN
    return (left, top)
    return(left, top)

def getBoxAtPixel(x, y):
    for boxx in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for boxy in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            left,top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy)
            boxRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE)
            if boxRect.collidepoint(x, y):
                return (boxx, boxy)
    return(None, None)

def drawIcon(shape, color, boxx, boxy):
    quarter = int(BOXSIZE * 0.25)
    half = int(BOXSIZE * 0.5)

    left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy)
    if shape == DONUT:
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left + half, top + half), half - 5)
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BGCOLOR, (left + half, top + half), quarter - 5)
    elif shape == SQUARE:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color,(left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE - half))
    elif shape == DIAMOND:
        pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF, color,((left + half, top), (left + BOXSIZE - 1, top + half), (left + half, top + BOXSIZE - 1), (left, top + half)))
    elif shape == LINES:
        for i in range(0, BOXSIZE, 4):
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left, top + i), (left + i, top))
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left + i, top + BOXSIZE - 1), (left + BOXSIZE - 1, top + i))
    elif shape == OVAL:
        pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, color, (left, top + quarter, BOXSIZE, half))

def getShapeAndColor(board, boxx, boxy):
    return board[boxx][boxy][0], board[boxx][boxy][1] 

def drawBoxCovers(board, boxes, coverage):
    for box in boxes:
        left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(box[0], box[1]) 
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BGCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
        shape, color = getShapeAndColor(board, box[0], box[1])
        drawIcon(shape, color, box[0], box[1])
        if coverage > 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, coverage, BOXSIZE))
            pygame.display.update()
            FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
def revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxesToReveal):
    for coverage in range(BOXSIZE, (-REVEALSPEED) - 1, - REVEALSPEED): 
        drawBoxCovers(board, boxesToReveal, coverage)

def coverBoxesAnimation(board, boxesToReveal):
    for coverage in range(BOXSIZE, (-REVEALSPEED) - 1, -REVEALSPEED):
        drawBoxCovers(board, boxesToReveal, coverage) 


def drawBoard(board, revealed):
    for boxx in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for boxy in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy)
            if not revealed[boxx][boxy]:
                pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BOXCOLOR, (left, top, BOXSIZE, BOXSIZE))
            else:
                    shape, color = getShapeAndColor(board, boxx, boxy)
                    drawIcon(shape, color, boxx, boxy)


def drawHighlightBox(boxx, boxy):
    left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, HIGHLIGHTCOLOR, (left - 5, top - 5, BOXSIZE + 10, BOXSIZE + 10), 4)


def startGameAnimation(board):
    coveredBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)
    boxes = [0]
    for x in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            boxes.append( (x,y) )
    random.shuffle(boxes)
    boxGroups = splitIntoGroupsOf(8, boxes)

    drawBoard(board, coveredBoxes)
    for boxGroup in boxGroups:
        revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxGroups)
        coverBoxesAnimation(board, boxGroups)

def gameWonAnimation(board):
    coveredBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(True)
    color1 = LIGHTBGCOLOR
    color2 = BGCOLOR

    for i in range(13):
       color1, color2 = color2, color1
       DISPLAYSURF.fill(color1)
       drawBoard(board, coveredBoxes)
       pygame.display.update()
       pygame.time.wait(300)

def hasWon(revealedBoxes):
    for i in revealedboxes:
        if False in i:
            return False
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO please go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write a minimal question.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated program to try and run as a beginner.  It's also way too much code to post when you have such a specific error.  You'll help yourself and others who come to your post looking for answers if you put in the work to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example, as gommb already noted.  Having said that: In `startGameAnimation()`, use `boxGroup` instead of `boxGroups` inside your `boxGroups` for-loop - that's causing the problem.

Comment: And please don't use the "code snippet" feature for Python. It's for HTML / CSS / JavaScript that will run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add/concatenate a tuple to a integer.

```
left = boxx*(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + XMARGIN
```

If you want add `XMARGIN` to both the elements in tuple `boxx*(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE)`, then do it this way  `boxx*(BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE) + (XMARGIN, XMARGIN)`